# Bash script and Command line arguments

Tags: c++, bash, pbs

So I have a file that is called "run_correlation_study.pbs" and "correlation_study.pbs". In correlation_study.pbs, I run a bash script that uses portable batch software(pbs) and assign 3 command line arguments that will be used in my actual program. In run_correlation_study.pbs, I loop through the command line arguments that are used in correlation_study.pbs so that I can split up my program into multiple jobs for a computing cluster. However, I have been getting errors with my run_correlation_study.pbs file when I try to run it (I turn it into an executable file before running it). I have posted both file below, run_correlation_study.pbs is listed first and correlation_study.pbs is listed second. I can provide the part of my program where the command line arguments are used but I do not think the problem is caused in there. Also, the error/text that shows up when I try to run my program is listed last.

Run_correlation_study.pbs:

```
    for ((ARC_LENGTH = 0; ARC_LENGTH <= 35; ARC_LENGTH++)); do
       qsub -v ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH/10, RANDOM_NUM_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH correlation_study.pbs
    done
```

Correlation_study.pbs:

```
    #PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
    #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
    #PBS -N Correlation_study_data
    #PBS -j oe
    #PBS -m abe

    #COMMANDS TO RUN
    cd /home/kovacevich.9/correlation_study/corrstudies
    ./correlation_study.x ${ARC_LENGTH_ARG} ${RANDOM_NUM_ARG}
```

Error/text:

```
   usage: qsub [-a date_time] [-A account_string] [-b secs]
   [-c [ none | { enabled | periodic | shutdown |
   depth=<int> | dir=<path> | interval=<minutes>}... ]
   [-C directive_prefix] [-d path] [-D path]
   [-e path] [-h] [-I] [-j oe] [-k {oe}] [-l resource_list] [-m n 
   {abe}]
   [-M user_list] [-N jobname] [-o path] [-p priority] [-P proxy_user] 
   [-q queue] 
   [-r y|n] [-S path] [-t number_to_submit] [-T type]  [-u user_list] 
   [-w] path
   [-W additional_attributes] [-v variable_list] [-V ] [-x] [-X] [-z] 
   [script]
```

Portion of program:

```
    if(argc == 3)
    {
       double test_arc_length = atof(argv[1]);
       unsigned long int seed = atoi(argv[2]);
```

Comment: What dies this have to do with C++?

Comment: `-v ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH/10, RANDOM_NUM_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH` is three separate arguments passed to the program: `-v`, `ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH/10,` and `RANDOM_NUM_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH`. My guess is that you should use `-v ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH/10,RANDOM_NUM_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH` instead (note the lack of space after the comma)

Comment: Are you aware that `$ARC_LENGTH/10` is just a string, not the result of dividing a value by 10? If not, you are also probably not aware that the shell doesn't do floating-point arithmetic. `$((25/10))` is 2, not 2.5.

Comment: Also note that the shell will not do any arithmetic for `$ARC_LENGTH/10`. It will simply expand the `ARC_LENGTH` variable and append the string `/10`. I suggest you read [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), especially the section about [arithmetic evaluation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#ARITHMETIC_EVALUATION) if you intend to do a real division.

Comment: I used the atof function in my program to convert from a string to a double so that should work right? Also, I will try to run the program with the space removed now

Comment: No, `atof` will not divide numbers, it'll just return the first one it parses.

Comment: So when the argument is 1/10 is passed into the program, atof will not produce .1 and instead only see 1? I am a little confused, also deleting the extra space worked and I am not sure why. Also, I use atoi to convert RANDOM_NUM_ARG from a string to integer but that should be fine? I edited my post to include the portion of the code that converts from strings to numbers.

Comment: Yes, `atof` will parse `1/10` as `1`, not `0.1`. Deleting the space in between worked because with space, you were passing two separate arguments, one belonging to `-v` option, and one positional. You can also try wrapping the list with double quotes, like: `-v "ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH/10, RANDOM_NUM_ARG=$ARC_LENGTH"`, that way space is preserved, and `-v` gets the complete list as a single argument.

Comment: The C code you added, does not handle `-v` option at all.

Comment: Why is that? Isn't -v used to handle multiple arguments?

Comment: It's not clear from the portion you inserted how are you handling arguments parsing, `getopt`? If you read directly from `argv` (as the code suggests), how are you handling other options?

Comment: I do not think I understand what you're saying so I apologize for that but I will try to explain how I think the arugments are parsed. Since I have 3 arguments then argc should equal 3 and I can use atof(argv[1]) to pass the value of ARC_LENGTH_ARG into my program and the same for atoi(argv[2]) which should contain the value of RANDOM_NUM_ARG into the program and convert it into a integer. I do not understand the use of getopt but would appreciate it if you could explain a little more?

Comment: The "usage" for qsub says it handles multiple options and switches, `-v` being only one of them. How do you handle all those? The [`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt) is a standard `libc` way of parsing command line options.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why printing a usage statement instead of a good error message is incorrect behavior.  Rather than reporting a generic usage statement, the program ought to say something specific like `unexpected argument: RANDOM_NUM_ARG=...` which would point the user to the error.

Answer (score 0):

To do floating point arithmetic from bash, you need to call out to an external program. You could do one of:

```
qsub -v "ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$(bc -l <<<"$ARC_LENGTH/10"),..."
qsub -v "ARC_LENGTH_ARG=$(awk -v "a=$ARC_LENGTH" 'BEGIN {print a/10}'),..."
```

Using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) syntax `$(cmd ...)` within a double quoted string.